# How to ignore events raised in the constructor by loading aggregate roots?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I see that some people raise domain events in the constructor of aggregate roots. https://github.com/szjani/predaddy/blob/4.0/tests/src/predaddy/domain/User.php What is the best way to ignore these events when I load my aggregate root from the database?

Comment: Are we sure that raising domain events in a constructor is a good idea?  Maybe the best way to work around the issue is to not use that idiom at all.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Good point, but where to use them then? Currently I read something related from Udi Dahan. Maybe it answers the question: https://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/

Comment: You should define a default constructor for ORMs to load the data and make it private (depends on ORM feature supports). Best place to put your domain events is in factory method pattern.

Comment: @inf3rno - the long answer is come to the ddd-cqrs-es slack and have a conversation: https://discord.gg/sEZGSHNNbH -- the digest version is (a) raising events is a questionable way to manage the communication of information within an aggregate, (b) raising events to share information between aggregates happens outside of the domain model, and (c) the events that document the "creation" of a domain object are not themselves a product of the constructor.  the TL;DR version is the literature sucks, and easy-but-wrong takes are out competing the subtle-but-correct takes.

Answer (score 0):

I checked several articles in the topic and most of them use factory method for creation and some of them factory or builder patterns. Raising the domain event in the constructor appears to be an anti-pattern. Thanks for the comments, which pointed this out and lead me to the right direction!

- https://aneshas.medium.com/c-event-sourcing-example-with-tactical-ddd-and-aperture-4ade39cbaac3
- https://www.dandoescode.com/blog/domain-driven-design-patterns-for-aggregate-creation-mastery
- https://medium.com/@edin.sahbaz/exploring-the-power-of-aggregates-in-domain-driven-design-and-clean-architecture-6408d6128d3b
- https://eventsourcing.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/domain.html